# Change language Spanish labels to create digital signature with iText PDFStamper

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using iText 5.4 PDFStamper for the digital signature on my PDF documents with the following code:

```
stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setReason("SANABRIA.");
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72 + 88 * (numeroFirma - 1), 732, 144 + 88 * (numeroFirma - 1), 780), 1, nombreCertificado);

ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(privateKey, "SHA-256", "BC");
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, certificates, null, null, null, 0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

The signature is generated and displayed correctly in PDF:

**Digitally signed by jsanabria**

**Date: 2015.04.28 18:23:23 BOT**

**Reason: SANABRIA**

But what I need is to change the labels to Spanish, to be well imprinted on the PDF, that is:

Digitally signed by to *Firmado digitalmente por*, Date to *Fecha* and Reason to *Razón*

**Firmado digitalmente por jsanabria**

**Fecha: 2015.04.28 18:23:23 BOT**

**Razón: SANABRIA**

Please help as I could change the language of the labels, are thanked.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify any custom text for the signature appearance:

```
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setReason("SANABRIA.");
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72 + 88 * (numeroFirma - 1),
    732, 144 + 88 * (numeroFirma - 1), 780), 1, nombreCertificado);
// Custom signature appearance text
appearance.setLayer2Text("Firmado digitalmente ...");
```